# How to read the individual value from the ViewModel in MVC in View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I am trying to read the value of a particular property in view from ViewModel. But I am unable.  See the code below and look at the "check". "check is assignable at one place but then I am unable to read its value in the view.

```
@{string check;} //created a variable

       @foreach (var item in @Model )
       {
               check = "yes"; //this is good
                return;
                
        }         
 

   @{if(check=="yes")}  //this here show the error not recognizing the check.
```

---

or

```
@{
string check;

 @foreach (var item in @Model )
{
     check =item.FirstTime;
    return;
}

if(check!=0)  //this is unrecognized
}
```

Comment: The IDE is not liking that it's potentially uninitialized... change to @{string check="no";}  ?

Comment: You could try to assign the variable outside the loop. You could assign the value just after creating it. `@{string check;  check = "yes";}` Then if you try to check like this `@{if (check == "yes") {ViewData["Title"] ="xyz"; }}`. It will work.